# Could not resolve dependency tree angular tslib

Tags: angular, npm, dependency-tree

npm install gives the following error (please refer the image)

[image]

cli version is Angular CLI: 9.1.8
Please help. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

so after a lot of trouble shooting, got to know that the node versions were different and conflicting. in the terminal, though the node version was the latest, some of the files of node older version were not deleted and hence got this error while npm install. so deleted the files manually, uninstalled latest version of node. reinstalled it.
after doing npm install --force, i got to know about the version mess.
somehow, clearing the cache did not help either. wonder why. but any how, it works now.